# What is a username exactly used for in arXiv?

Tags: authorship, arxiv

This is a fairly simple question, which any arXiv author could answer: the username set while registering in arXiv is not the authorial name users see when they read a paper you've published, right? The arXiv username set during registration is merely so that the author can log into arXiv?

Comment: Yes. Username is used for the author himself to login into the arxiv system, not what the readers see.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Here is [my most recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01529), and you can't find my arXiv username anywhere on the page.

There is a *separate* notion of "author ID", which is specifically *for* the purpose of [collecting all your papers on one page](https://arxiv.org/a/church_t_1.html), but you have to set that up separately afterwards. It's not the same as the username.